# If, elif, and else statements not working/not being recognized by python when inside a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop

I'm trying to write a little horoscope program that takes in a zodiac sign as an input and runs through a series of other questions that also require input. I'm struggling to figure out why the elif and else statements are not working. Here's my code.

```
import requests
import textwrap as tr

# yesterday = "http://sandipbgt.com/theastrologer/api/horoscope/{sunsign}/yesterday"
# tomorrow = "http://sandipbgt.com/theastrologer/api/horoscope/{sunsign}/tomorrow"
# today = "http://sandipbgt.com/theastrologer/api/horoscope/{sunsign}/today"
# sunsign_list = "http://sandipbgt.com/theastrologer/api/horoscope/{sunsign}/sunsigns"

signs = requests.get("http://sandipbgt.com/theastrologer/api/sunsigns").json()

sign_dates = {'Aries:': 'March 21 - April 19', 'Taurus:': 'April 20 – May 20', 'Gemini:': 'May 21 – June 20', 'Cancer:': 'June 21 – July 22', 'Leo:': 'July 23 – August 22', 'Virgo:': 'August 23 – September 22', 'Libra:': 'September 23 – October 22', 'Scorpio:': 'October 23 – November 21', 'Sagittarius:': 'November 22 – December 21', 'Capricorn:': 'December 22 – January 19', 'Aquarius:': 'January 20 – February 18', 'Pisces:': 'February 19 – March 20'}

i = 1

while i == 1:
    input("Are you ready to check out your horoscope? \n\n"
          "Please enter 'yes' or 'no'. ")

    if input == 'yes' or 'Yes' or 'YES':
        print('Okay cool! check out the list of zodiac signs and their corresponding dates below! ')
        print('Zodiac sign list below: ')
        print('')

        for key, value in sign_dates.items():
            print(key, value)

        '''another method to print the key, value pairs of sign_date dictionary.
    result = '\n'.join(f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in sign_dates.items())
    print(result)'''

        selectedSign = input('\nWhat sign are you?:\n')

        timeframe = input("Do you want your horoscope for 'today', 'tomorrow', or 'yesterday'? ")

        horoscope = requests.get(f"http://sandipbgt.com/theastrologer/api/horoscope/{selectedSign}/{timeframe}").json()
        print(str(horoscope))

        input('Pretty cool huh?\n\n'
              'Would you like to check another timeframe or check another zodiac sign? ')

        if input == 'yes' or 'Yes' or 'YES':
            print('Okay cool! Sending you to main menu:')
            i = 1

        elif input != 'yes' or 'Yes' or 'YES':
            print('Okay! Have a good one!')
            break

    elif input == 'no' or 'No' or 'NO':
        print('Okay! Have a good one!')
        break

    else:
        print('Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again!')
        i = 1
```

The elif and else statements are not working and they are ignored. Also, the if and elif statements within the most outer if statement don't work properly as well. I could enter in a no for the inputs and the program is still running through the most outer if statement flow. Would anyone be able to give me some advice on how I could fix this? Thank you, I appreciate it.

I tried entering yes when prompted to answer the first input question and it works fine except for when I reach the if, elif statements within the most outer if statement.

I tried entering no and a random input when prompted to answer the first input question and the program still acts as if I answered yes to the original input question.

Comment: Check out what 'a' or 'b' is in python. You are asking if a string is equal to a Boolean. Your if clause will never trigger. Use the in keyword instead.

Comment: All of your if statements reference `input`, which would just call the built-in function. `>>> input
<built-in function input>`. Instead, you want something like `input_data = intput('your question')` and then use `input_data` in the if statement

Comment: I tried assigned the input to a variable and then used the variable in the if statement and it still didn't work. I also tried this:  if input_data == str('yes'): and that didn't work either. jlandercy, I'm not too sure what you mean?

Comment: I used the in keyword like you said and it worked. I said, if input_data in {'yes', 'Yes', 'YES'}:

That worked. Thanks jlandercy